# Cross-Validation and SMOTE in WEKA

Tags: python, weka, cross-validation

I am trying to run 5-fold cross-validation on WEKA using a FilteredClassifier with SMOTE.

To my knowledge, I should apply SMOTE in each of the CV folds to obtain my CV error.

Does anyone have documentation or background on how WEKA performs CV in a FilteredClassifier using

```
Evaluation().crossvalidate_model(INPUTS)
```

I am using python with the weka-wrapper.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka treats the `FilteredClassifier` meta-classifier just like any other classifier (since they both implement the `weka.classifiers.Classifier` interface).

If you're performing 5-fold CV, then the data gets split into 5 pairs of train/test folds and each time the classifier gets trained with the training fold and then evaluated on the test fold. The `weka.classifiers.Evaluation` class records the statistics obtained from the test data of each of the folds.

In your case (for each train/test fold), the `FilteredClassifier` uses the training data to initialize the `SMOTE` filter and filter it before building the base-classifier with it.

So the answer is yes, your `SMOTE` filter gets initialized and applied in each of the CV folds.

The official place for Weka questions is the [Weka mailing list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist).